# Countablity of these sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory

There are two sets,

> > $X=\{\{x_n\}: x_n \in \{0,1\}\}$
> >
> > $Y=\{\{y_n\}: y_n =1 \text{ for at most finitely many $n$}\}$

I want to investigate

> > $X,Y$ countable/finite/uncountable/infinite?

What I am getting we can define the sequence $x_n$ in countably infinite ways (e.g. $x_n=(\sin x)^n$). So may be $X$ have same cardinality with $\mathbb{N}$. I dont know about $Y$.

Comment: Consider $f:X\to[0,1]$ defined by $f(\{x_n\})=\sum_n x_n/2^{n+1}$ and observe that the image of $f$ is $[0,1)$. So, $X$ is not smaller than $[0,1)$. Try the same formula for $f$ but from $Y$ to $[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

$X:=$ the set of all sequences whose elements are the digit $0$ and $1$, so uncountable.

> *Here's a Rudin's Proof:*
>
> *Idea:* To prove any countable subset of $X$ is a proper subset of $X$, it follows that $X$ is uncountable.
>
> So let $E$ be a countable subset of $X$ and $E$ consist of the sequnces $s_1,s_2,...$.
>
> We construct a sequence $s$ as follows:
>
> If the $n^{th}$ digit in $s_n$ is $1$, then we let the $n^{th}$ digit of $s$ is $0$ and vice versa. Then $s$ differs from every member of $E$ in atleast one place. So $s \notin E$. But $s \in X$.

$Y:=$ the set of all sequences which are eventually zero, so ......